# Comparatives and superlatives for compound adjectives

Tags: word-usage

In a composition, I'm trying to make a comparison between three characters who, besides other unfavorable traits, are extremely rude and grabby. Choosing synonyms for the description, I faced the problem of using comparatives and superlatives of the adjectives *ill-bred* and *tight-fisted*.

Michael Swan says that some compound adjectives, such as *good-looking* and *well-known*, have two possible comparatives and superlatives - better/best-looking/known and more/most good-looking/well-known, but he still says "*some* compound adjectives", and I have found no other examples.

The question is:

What about the two which trouble me? Would it be correct and natural for a native English speaker to use *"the tightest-fisted of the three"* or *"he's even iller-bred than the two"*, or will the use of *more/the most* with the compound adjectives like these be always a safe path?

Comment: Just a comment, since I don't have sources or logic really, but as a native speaker "the most tight-fisted" or "more ill-bread" sound natural, while "the tightest-fisted" etc. sound very strange.

Comment: I agree with the above comment; “ill-bread” sounds quite unnatural as well because the correct spelling of the adjective is “ill-bred”. See [here](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/ill-bred) for the comparative and the superlative forms.

Comment: Of course it's ill-bred, thanks for pointing out and for the link.

Comment: *lll* traditionally takes *worse* and *worst* as its comparative and superlative grades: *He's even worse-bred than the others*. I have no problem with *tighter-fisted*, but *tightest-fisted* is a tongue-twister!

Comment: StoneyB@ Thanks a lot for the tip, it is really useful. Smiling trying the tongue-twister.

Comment: Would we use lower-bred or more low-bred?

Comment: The comparative is only used between pairs of an item.  To use it in a group of three you would have to say "he's even more ill-bred than either of the other two" (as this means that you are making a series of comparisons of pairs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you asked about other compound adjectives. Allow me to list some:

- long-lasting
- far-reaching
- high-ranked
- short-term
- high-level
- low-price

With regards to the question you pose, whether to use the superlative or more/most construction, @StoneyB is pretty spot-on (pun intended); with respect to writing for comprehension, the more/most construction is a safer bet. However, as long as the proper superlative is being used (such as ill-bred to worse-bred, or tight-fisted to tightest-fisted), use of that form is no less correct.

Comment: I'd say that it's on a case-by-case basis, and generally it would be more/most except in cases where the other usage is established.  All your examples can be used without more/most, but I'm struggling to think of any others.